# Initialization of Spring MVC Model properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts

In an old version of my project I used Struts 1.x with ActionsForm-classes.

Let's say there is a property 'count' of type 'Long' in my form-class.
If I call an action-class, which accepts this form-class, the property's value is automatically set to '0'.

No I migrated to Spring MVC - and use model-classes instead of form-classes. But they look quite the same - so there is also a property 'count' of type 'Long'.

Now, I call my controller-class:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/dosomething")
public ModelAndView list(@ModelAttribute MyModelClass myModelClass) {
```

When I look into 'myModelClass', the 'count' property is null. 
But as in Struts, I want it to be 0 by default.

How can this be done?

Comment: By assigning it a default value in the model object.

Comment: That could be one solution, but it seems quick and dirty to me. If I should always have a look on default values and write some extra code, the advantage of using model-classes seems gone..

Comment: Why, all the information is in the model object so not sure what is wrong with that. The default value for any object is `null` so if yu want something else use `long` instead of the object wrapper, or assign a default value in the form you are submitting (on the client).

Answer (score 0):

Default value for Long (Wrapper Class) is null. Hence your MyModelClass is having null value in count. Use primitive long if you want default value 0.